# What's the meaning of "bulk rate"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

As per [this joke from xkcd.com](https://xkcd.com/605/) , what's the meaning of *bulk rate*?

[image: "XKCD" comic "Extrapolating"]

> "As you can see, by late next month you'll have over four dozen husbands. Better get a **bulk rate** on wedding cake."

I understand "bulk" is a bunch of elements, but does it mean in this context that *you get a better price if you buy many*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In context, it is a discount for purchasing in quantity. See also, "[wholesale pricing](http://www.indieretailacademy.com/pricing-for-wholesale-and-retail/)".

Answer (score 2):

Package delivery companies give discounts, a better rate, to frequent customers.  So if you have a large **bulk** of material to send, you get a better **rate**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Had to choose one, preferred the one defining without using the defined word.